# Android Room Database: Autogenerated bind() function throws an incompatible types error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a Room database for Android. I'm not too experienced with this, so I've been following some guides on it, trying to adapt it to what I need it for. Upon building, I get the following error: `error: incomparable types: boolean and <null> _tmp = _tmp_1 == null ? null : (_tmp_1 ? 1 : 0);` from the Dao Impl file, which is autogenerated.

The generated code which throws this error is:

```java
@Override
public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Product value) {
  final Integer _tmp;
  final boolean _tmp_1;
  _tmp_1 = value.getId() != 0;
  _tmp = _tmp_1 == null ? null : (_tmp_1 ? 1 : 0);
```

This same exact error is in all the Dao implementations, so I'm not sure what the issue here is.

I have three Daos, this is the code for them:

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface ProductDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
    fun getAll(): List<Product>
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
    fun getProductById(id: Int): Product
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE name LIKE :name")
    fun getProductByName(name: String): Product
    @Query("SELECT id FROM product_table WHERE name LIKE :name")
    fun getId(name: String): Int
    @Transaction
    @Insert(entity = Product::class)
    suspend fun insert(product: Product)
    @Transaction
    @Delete
    suspend fun drop(product: Product)
    @Query("DELETE FROM product_table")
    suspend fun dropAll()
}
```

```kotlin
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface ReportDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM report_table WHERE reportId = :reportId LIMIT 1")
    fun getReport(reportId: Int): Report
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(report: Report)
    @Delete
    suspend fun drop(report: Report)
}
```

```kotlin
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
    fun getUserById(id: Int): User
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(user: User)
    @Delete
    suspend fun drop(user: User)
}
```

The error comes from the generated constructor to the implementation class:

```java
this.__insertionAdapterOfProduct = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Product>(__db) {
  @Override
  public String createQuery() {
    return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `product_table` (`id`,`name`,`parts`) VALUES (nullif(?, 0),?,?)";
  }

  @Override
  public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Product value) {
    final Integer _tmp;
    final boolean _tmp_1;
    _tmp_1 = value.getId() != 0;
    _tmp = _tmp_1 == null ? null : (_tmp_1 ? 1 : 0);
    if (_tmp == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(1);
    } else {
      stmt.bindLong(1, _tmp);
    }
    if (value.getName() == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(2);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(2, value.getName());
    }
    final String _tmp_2;
    _tmp_2 = __dataConverter().fromStringList(value.getParts());
    if (_tmp_2 == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(3);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(3, _tmp_2);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I see in your code _tmp_1 variable type primitive so it can't be null.

I am suggesting you to remove this unnecessary part from your code `_tmp_1 == null ? null : `

Comment: I guess I wasn't too clear on this, the code that gives the error is automatically generated, so I cannot change anything about the code, otherwise I would.

Comment: May you also provide your entitiy classes please, if your issue still actual

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has been resolved already, but I'll post anyway, should someone seek this info later.

So the problem, at least in my case, was not in any of the Dao files, but rather in the entities. However, the android studio provided error message is very uninformative and does not point to the entity class in the slightest.

The problem was that my entity had a double value and it had getter as per usual. I tried to return a more printing friendly value by rounding the double into closest integer and returning that instead of the double value. What I didn't know was that the Dao implementation file (autogenerated) uses that same getter and expects to get a double in return. Long story short, if your doing something funny to your entity values, don't do it in the getters.

**TLDR; Make sure your entity class getters return correct types**